# Added js file is not working nor throws it any errors

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

I add a js file with form_alter and #attached. Everything works fine.

```
    function ganzech_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
      switch ($form_id) {
        case 'anbieter_node_form':
          $form['#attached']['js'] = array(
            drupal_get_path('module', 'ganzech') . '/ganzech.js',
            );

          break;

      }
      return;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KuqHT/3/ (click the first Checkbox to see what it does)
This works even on jQuery 1.4.x. My Drupal has 1.5.2
You can see the file here: http://www.fsd-vss.ch/sites/all/modules/custom/ganzech/ganzech.js

I have it included on my form in `node/add/anbieter` The HTML on that node looks like this

```
<div class="form-item form-type-checkboxes form-item-field-kantone-und">
  <label for="edit-field-kantone-und">Kantone <span class="form-required" title="Diese Angabe wird benötigt.">*</span></label>
 <div id="edit-field-kantone-und" class="form-checkboxes"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-Ganze-Schweiz">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-ganze-schweiz" name="field_kantone[und][Ganze Schweiz]" value="Ganze Schweiz" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-ganze-schweiz">Ganze Schweiz </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-AG">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-ag" name="field_kantone[und][AG]" value="AG" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-ag">AG </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-AI">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-ai" name="field_kantone[und][AI]" value="AI" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-ai">AI </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-AR">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-ar" name="field_kantone[und][AR]" value="AR" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-ar">AR </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-BE">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-be" name="field_kantone[und][BE]" value="BE" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-be">BE </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-BL">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-bl" name="field_kantone[und][BL]" value="BL" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-bl">BL </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-BS">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-bs" name="field_kantone[und][BS]" value="BS" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-bs">BS </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-FL">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-fl" name="field_kantone[und][FL]" value="FL" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-fl">FL </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-FR">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-fr" name="field_kantone[und][FR]" value="FR" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-fr">FR </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-GE">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-ge" name="field_kantone[und][GE]" value="GE" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-ge">GE </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-GL">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-gl" name="field_kantone[und][GL]" value="GL" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-gl">GL </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-GR">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-gr" name="field_kantone[und][GR]" value="GR" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-gr">GR </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-JU">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-ju" name="field_kantone[und][JU]" value="JU" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-ju">JU </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-LU">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-lu" name="field_kantone[und][LU]" value="LU" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-lu">LU </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-NE">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-ne" name="field_kantone[und][NE]" value="NE" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-ne">NE </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-NW">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-nw" name="field_kantone[und][NW]" value="NW" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-nw">NW </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-OW">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-ow" name="field_kantone[und][OW]" value="OW" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-ow">OW </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-SG">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-sg" name="field_kantone[und][SG]" value="SG" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-sg">SG </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-SH">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-sh" name="field_kantone[und][SH]" value="SH" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-sh">SH </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-SO">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-so" name="field_kantone[und][SO]" value="SO" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-so">SO </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-SZ">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-sz" name="field_kantone[und][SZ]" value="SZ" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-sz">SZ </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-TG">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-tg" name="field_kantone[und][TG]" value="TG" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-tg">TG </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-TI">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-ti" name="field_kantone[und][TI]" value="TI" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-ti">TI </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-UR">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-ur" name="field_kantone[und][UR]" value="UR" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-ur">UR </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-VD">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-vd" name="field_kantone[und][VD]" value="VD" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-vd">VD </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-VS">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-vs" name="field_kantone[und][VS]" value="VS" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-vs">VS </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-ZG">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-zg" name="field_kantone[und][ZG]" value="ZG" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-zg">ZG </label>

</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-field-kantone-und-ZH">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-kantone-und-zh" name="field_kantone[und][ZH]" value="ZH" class="form-checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-field-kantone-und-zh">ZH </label>

</div>
</div>
<div class="description">Wo liegt das Einsatzgebiet der Firma?</div>
</div>
```

Can it be, it has something to do with `jQuery(this).is(':checked'));`?
But why is my pastie working even with jQuery 1.4.x and why I don't get any Errors if its that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the JS file. Not working:

```
jQuery('#edit-field-kantone-und-ganze-schweiz').bind('change', function ( ) {
     jQuery(':checkbox').attr('checked', jQuery(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

working:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
jQuery('#edit-field-kantone-und-ganze-schweiz').bind('change', function ( ) {
     jQuery(':checkbox').attr('checked', jQuery(this).is(':checked'));
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it like this:

```
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(drupal_get_path('module', 'ganzech') . '/ganzech.js' => array('type' => 'file'),);
```

This way is clearly specified that it is a file.

And of course please check for the name of the module. Some type errors could always mess with your code.

Comment: The file gets included, either way. It's also getting executed. If I throw in an `alert();` it will show up. So the problem lies in the JS itself.